# How do I simulate the joystick of a PS4 controller on a PC using C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, emulation, device-emulation

I've been creating a program to play games on a computer, but the controls are on my phone.
But, I didn't know how to simulate the joystick, so I searched online.

[In this website](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/239050/actual-joystick-emulation-in-c), someone said that I need to make my own device driver to simulate it, but in  [this website](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1113553/Is-there-a-way-to-emulate-joystick-signals-program) (Solution 2), it says that you could do it using [Joystick Notification Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/joystick-notification-messages?redirectedfrom=MSDN). I looked it up, but it seems like it only supports C++, not C#.

[This previous website](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1113553/Is-there-a-way-to-emulate-joystick-signals-program) (Solution 1) also stated that you could do it by faking an rs232 serial port, however I do not know what that means, nor do I have the tools to do it.

I used Unity for the program, so I figured, if I made a post on Unity Forum, I would get an answer. Turns out, I didn't get an answer. [(link to my thread on the forum)](https://forum.unity.com/threads/simulating-joystick-input-with-c.994405/)

Is there any way to simulate the joystick of a PS4 controller using C#, preferably without external programs and device drivers, or am I stuck using [vJoy](http://vjoystick.sourceforge.net/site/index.php/download-a-install/download) or [ViGEm](https://github.com/ViGEm?language=c%23)?

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: You must have though of this yourself, or might be useless, but just in case. You can code yourself a function that returns values from -1 to 1 in the different axis accumulating the number of button inputs. You have x and y values in the joystick turn both axis, where (0, 0) is the idle joystick position. You can handle those two static values from -1 to 1 handled with the up, down, left, right arrows for example.

Comment: Oh, and I also forgot to mention that I have no access to the source code of the game I was playing, so I can't modify how it works. The only way is to simulate PS4 joystick inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using [ViGEm](https://forums.vigem.org/topic/273/vigem-net-feeder-example-step-by-step), which is compatible with C#. ViGEm is a gamepad emulation program for C# that supports XBOX 360 and PS4 controllers.
The reason I use ViGEm instead of [vJoy](http://vjoystick.sourceforge.net/site/index.php/77-vjoy/84-homepage-v200) is because ViGEm has simpler instructions and a forum.